Which option would best fit my episodic series?
So I have this base idea of this story about a vampiric, tentacled monster(s) that put people into a dreamworld/illusion/matrix called Reveries so they can feed on their blood. It also follows a man that is trying to sabotage the creature(s) and prevent people getting ’mindviolated’ and fed on. This story is episodic, with each chapter being centered around a new client/victim and their Reverie, with new information on the world and creature(s) and a slight overarching plot unfolding each chapter as well.
The problem I have is trying to work out which of 2 different paths I want to take the story into that I want to go with.
The first one focuses on a single one of these entities and his/its hosts are usually willing clients that seek him/it out for his ability to place them into a Reverie that usually last a few days at most. The dude stopping him/it is also just physically trying to do so(not in a violent manner) and is investigating other his/its abilities and his/its past history.
The 2nd is there not being 1 singular entity doing this, but rather a worldful of them. The victims are typically not willing, fully at least. They are also less intelligent than the other vamp, though not stupid. The man trying to stop this instead of investing physically and so forth, is able to somehow hack into a Reverie in order to help them escape if they are willing to leave.
So any of you guys that write fiction alot, can you suggest the version I go with. I just want to go with one that jives with my episodic format and slight overarching plot structure.

Who is the Protagonist?
Tentacle Monster Vampire – I'm just gonna be honest, this does not sound like a relatable protagonist.
Occult Detective Hero – an iconic archetype on a mission, probably does not have an arc. Might be an anti-hero since this character is the disrupter of the status quo.
Dr Watson – Companion/civilian character who can show a sense of wonder and uncertainty.
Guest Star of the Week – The series is structured like an anthology, each Reverie is its own self-contained story. The Dude is a witness who exists outside the story, similar to other anthology narrators like The Hitchhiker and The Whistler. He is aware of the conflict but has limited influence over it. Each Guest Star must face their inner-demons or be lost to the monster. Some win, some lose.
The Storytelling Iceberg

So I have this base idea of this story about a vampiric, tentacled
monster(s)...

In some ways, worldbuilding is the opposite of storytelling.
Your worldbuilding idea can be the backdrop for a lot of different types of stories (not just plots and characters). The vampires can be generic monsters. They can be a metaphor for drugdealers or loansharks or a for-profit healthcare. They can be an analogy for social dysfunction, false-religion, and poor life choices.
Meanwhile, the 'Dude' could be a crackpot that no one believes. He could be a one-man freedom fighter, he could be an undesirable that was rejected by the vampires. He could be a comicbook power fantasy. He could be more myth than real.
It all depends on your theme and what you want to say about this world and the people in it, ultimately as a contrast/commentary on how you as an author feel about life and the real world.
(Also commercial decisions like the publishing format, your target demographic, how long you can really keep milking the same cow as a series, whether it's open-ended or has a saga arc that ends.)
I'll point out the way the situation is described in the OP – starting with the vampires and their goal, then describing a hero, then describing the role of individuals – is the reverse order of how a story would usually be told. Typically the reader would meet an individual with their conflict. That person goes to the vampires for a solution, but the solution is this false Reverie which isn't a solution at all it's a compromise. Things get worse until the hero intervenes, which exposes the vampires. Out of the frying pan into the fire.
Worldbuilding tells us 'facts' all at once like a prolog infodump, but stories need to be treated like an iceberg. It is discovered in layers, by a protagonist who has no idea how deep it goes.
I suggest you need to choose your protagonist, and that will help you understand how they would be introduced to the story iceberg. This will also decide what type of theme you are telling – how the reader is intended to relate to the protagonist, and what they are suppose to feel as the story unfolds.
